# Entity or relationship

Tags: sql, ms-access, entity-relationship, cardinality

I am drawing an ER diagram. Movies (title, year, and rating) are shown in theaters (name and city). A movie can be shown in many theaters and a theater can show many movies.

"Show" should hold theater_name and title of the movie. Should "show" be the relation between movie and theater or should I draw a "showing" relation and link "show" entity to it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Data Normalisation

Where you state:

> "Show" should hold **theater_name** and **title** of the movie.

Consider [**normalising**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization) your data such that information pertaining to each distinct entity is held in a single table containing only a single instance of such entity.

For example, information pertaining to a movie (including its title) would be stored in the `Movies` table, and **only** in this table. Information pertaining to a theatre would be stored in the `Theatres` table and **only** in this table.

Each record in the `Movies` and `Theatres` tables would then be uniquely referenced using a separate primary key field (e.g. `Movie_ID` and `Theatre_ID`), for which I would recommend using a Long Integer Autonumber field.

From there on, whenever referencing a movie or a theatre in other tables, you would use only the relevant **ID**, and not carry across any other information.

Not only does this optimise the size & performance of your database (since integers occupy significantly less memory and can be indexed far more efficiently than strings), but you also need only maintain the data in a single location: if the name of a movie changes, you only need to change the data in the `Movies` table, and this will be automatically reflected by any query which references this table.

---

#### Junction Tables

To answer your question regarding how to represent the showing of movies in multiple theatres, with multiple theatres also showing the same movie: this many-to-many relationship requires the use of a [**junction table**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Associative_entity), also known as a **transaction table**, **bridge table**, **link table**, and many other names besides.

Such table provides a junction at which the `Movies` & `Theatres` table meet.

Bearing in mind the above advice concerning data normalisation, such a junction table should only include the unique ID for each Movie & Theatre, **not** the theatre name or movie title.

For example, such a table might look this like:

```
+------------+------------+----------+
| Showing_ID | Theatre_ID | Movie_ID |
+------------+------------+----------+
|          1 |          1 |        2 |
|          2 |          1 |        3 |
|          3 |          2 |        1 |
|        ... |        ... |      ... |
+------------+------------+----------+
```

Comment: thank you! I only link movie and theatre with "show" relation. So, title and theatre name become the foreign keys of the relation

Comment: @gzdddc I think you need to go back and re-read what Lee said. You want separate key IDs for your movies. How do you deal with two different versions of "Psycho" otherwise if the name is the key? Try to normalize as much as possible before building anything.

Comment: I should use "title" as a primary key. ID would be better as you said but I need to draw it according to the informations in the question

Comment: @gzdddc If this is a homework assignment which is forcing you to use a description as a foreign key, I think you need to teach your teacher about database normalisation (or find a better teacher).

Answer (score 0):

For creating an `n-to-n` relationship in a relational database you need a bridge table with two relationships, one per each table.
First of all, both `Movie` and `Theaters` need a column as primary key (e.g. `Id`) (`varchar` columns are not appropriate `PKs` and `FKs` in terms of performance). You also need a bridge table as you could have guessed (e.g. `Show`) with two foreign keys one `MoveiId` and one `TheaterId`.